# Export Particles from Maya to SceneKit iOS

Tags: ios, scenekit, maya, particle-system

I have a model in Maya with particles When export as DAE only models and animations are getting generated for the particles is blank node is generated. I wanted to export the particles and use them in iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible with SceneKit or any other API for iOS. The import does not support reading particles. The particle system in SceneKit is very basic for simple things. You would have to bake each particle as a geometry/model/animation instead.

Comment: Currently, your answer is matching looking for others opinion as well.